# Поиск и замена целого (точного) выражения на PHP

Tags: php

Нужно находить и заменять целые слова или точные выражения (точное совпадение) внутри строк. Например: найти "Половица" и заменить на "Половник" но не трогая при этом слова, которые начинаются на "Пол" (как это делает str_replace).
Использовал для этого **preg_replace**  Вот такой код:

```
$fcontent = preg_replace('/\bПоловица\b/i', 'Половник', $fcontent);
```

Но это решение выдает ошибку, скорее всего из-за кирилицы в словах. Помогите найти работающий regex код для поиска и замены точных фраз в кирилических фразах.

Comment: Модификатор `u` добавьте, а модификатор `i` уберите. Про модификаторы в php http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: @Visman сделал как вы написали и все-равно ошибка ": preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '�'" осталась как раньше.

Comment: Вы работает с текстами в кодировке UTF-8? У вас файл php сохранен в кодировке UTF-8?

Comment: Вопрос на инглише похожий на ваш https://stackoverflow.com/q/43918122/5441700

Comment: @Visman слова для замены подтягиваются через другой файл, но что первый, что второй - они оба сохранены в UTF-8, а также в корне есть htaccess где прописана AddDefaultCharset utf-8. Вот никак не могу разобраться что не так.

Comment: Посмотрите ответ на инглише по ссылке. Там вполне могут быть плохие символы, которые в кодировке UTF-8 не отображаются. Через hex редактор просмотрите строки.

Comment: Для замены ТОЧНЫХ вхождений неразумно использовать регулярные выражения. Для этого есть str_replace.

Comment: @Visman у меня в словах есть слешы, а также разные кавычки, в том числе и - {{}}, я думаю по этому не работает замена. Как можно эти лишние слешы и прочие символы, которые могут влиять на правила regex, превратить в обычный текст?

Comment: @Akina, напишите ответ как с помощью str_replace() заменить точно слова, а не части слов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию [preg_quote()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-quote.php) для обработки слов:

```
$word = 'Половица';
$to   = 'Половник';
$fcontent = preg_replace('/\b'.preg_quote($word, '/').'\b/u', $to, $fcontent);
```

И [модификатор](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `u` для работа с текстом в кодировке UTF-8

Comment: а можно еще как-то определить закончено ли предложение или нет? Например есть фраза "Отображать таблицей" и исходя из нашей формулы regex оно будет реагировать на слово "Отображать" не обращая внимание что там еще после пробела есть продолжение. Можно ли как-то это отследить?

Comment: @ЖеняДанілов, `^` - начало строки, `$` конец строки. Больше информации: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/info , https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%E3%F3%EB%FF%F0%ED%FB%E5_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%FF , http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.anchors.php

Answer (score 0):

Для много байтовых строк (utf8) используйте расширение mbstring. В вашем случае для регулярки подойдет ф-ция [mb_ereg_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-ereg-replace.php)